# How to send cookie to an external .cgi page with curl and php?

Tags: php, api, curl

I need to display security camera images on my web system in php. I'm using curl to try to accomplish this task. The integration consists of a login, and after that, the SessionID of the external server is generated and I need to send again to complete the authentication. However, the camera image is displayed. How can I do this? Here is the code I'm using:

```
<?php

$Cookie = (dirname(__FILE__) . "/cookie.txt");


# PRIMEIRA REQUISIÇÃO, RECEBE O COOKIE PARA O DOMINIO
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => $Cookie,
    CURLOPT_PORT => '8000',
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://camerasquadion.ddns.net:8000/camera.cgi',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_USERPWD =>  "usuario:senha",
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
));


$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err      = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);


if ($err) {
      echo "cURL Error #: <br>" . $err;
} else {
      //$this->Result = json_decode($response, true);
      echo "Resposta : " . $response;
}


# SEGUNDA REQUISIÇÃO, ENVIA O COOKIE RECEBIDO DE VOLTA PARA O DOMINIO
$ch = curl_init();
// Através da operação CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE estarei enviando meu COOKIE.
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => $Cookie,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://camerasquadion.ddns.net:8000/camera.cgi',
    //CURLOPT_URL => 'camerasquadion.ddns.net',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
));

$output = curl_exec($ch);


//print_r($output);

?>


<html>    
    <body>
        <h1>Access D-Guard</h1>
        <hr>

        <img src="http://camerasquadion.ddns.net:8000/camera.cgi?camera=108801&resolucao=640x480&qualidade=100&formato=jpg" />

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what is the `$output` of the second `curl_exec($ch)`?

Comment: This is unlikely to be a cookie problem. If a site requires basic HTTP auth, you need to send it with every request. The second request has the same URL as the first. Also, you aren't actually doing anything with the output from either request.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, and how can I solve this problem. Would you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the login/password are incorrect, so your first request fails.

Also, if you want to use PHP to authenticate and the final user to see the image immediately without authentication, you will need to download the image using curl - it will be in the `$response` of your first call, where you need to request the image url right away:

```
<?php
// ...
CURLOPT_URL => 'http://camerasquadion.ddns.net:8000/camera.cgi?camera=108801&resolucao=640x480&qualidade=100&formato=jpg',
```

Then you store the image on your server or just output it directly to the browser:

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,
<?=base64_encode($response)?>">
```

You might need to adjust the code to make it work, but this is the basic idea.

Again, the first step is having a valid username and password to pass the authentication.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It Works.